# Low noise electret mic circuit

Tags: audio, microphone, transmitter, electret

I wanna make a FM microphone for my guitar but the problem is that the electret mic itself output a lot of background noise even before amplifying its signal.

So obviously I need a preamp circuit but I don't need high gain or high volume. A low noise output with 1 volt peak to peak signal is ideal. But schematics I found online are relatively complicated and I don't know what they exactly do. So I would be grateful if anyone help with low noise preamp...

For the record this is FM transmitter circuit:

[image]

And microphone is just those ordinary mobile mics:

[image]

EDIT: At the moment I am just testing the microphone via PC sound card with TRS 3.5mm jack.

[image]

Comment: What makes you think the microphone is too noisy?  Have you looked at the microphone signal?  That transmitter will be pretty noisy itself.  The transmit frequency of that circuit is not really stable.  It will wander all over the place.  Depending on how it is built, it may also pick up interference from other equipment and broadcast it along with your microphone signal.

Comment: If the noise is coming from the microphone, then adding an amplifier would make the problem worse.

Comment: The 22k resistor powering the microphone is rather high.  Try using something around 2k.  Like, 2.2k or whatever common value resistor you have in that range.   Too much resistance in that spot could make the microphone a (little) bit noisier.  Try it.  It doesn't cost anything to swap out a resistor.  But, I think the real problem is the circuit.

Comment: i will try changing that resistor but at the moment i'm just testing the microphone output directly via PC soundcard. it has background noise even before FM broadcast !

Comment: i don't think it is microphone self noise. i have seen these kind of mics that output decent snr signal. could it be unstable audio jack input voltage?

Comment: The microphones are usually pretty good. That's why I doubted that as the problem to begin with.  How you connect it **can** cause problems, which is why I asked how you have it connected to your PC.

Comment: Is that going to line in, or to microphone in?

Comment: its connected to mic in !

Answer (score 1):

PC power rails are notoriously noisy. Here's the rest of the image that you used in your question (from [here](https://www.hobby-hour.com/electronics/computer_microphone.php)):

[image: sound card mic input]

Note that any noise on the power rail is coupled directly through the bias resistor to a high-gain audio input. I would recommend adding additional filtering:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flqw6X.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This creates an additional low-pass filter for the microphone bias voltage with a cutoff frequency of about 7 Hz.